# Customizing code completion on Sublime-text 2

Tags: html, customization, sublimetext

In Sublime-Text 2 when for instance in HTML5 I type:

"ul" and then the TAB key

The software show the following autocomplete code

```
<ul id="" class="">
<li><a href="" title=""></a></li>
li
 </ul><!-- / -->
```

I want to clean that code and customize it, I know is possible, anyone knows where can I edit this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/completions.html

Comment: Thanks :) But WHERE are completions files?, I just can't find'em